# How to prevent the TabControl from creating tab pages upon initializing VS 2017

Tags: c#, tabcontrol, tabpage

I am creating a tool that inherits from the TabControl. This is meant to function like TabControl, but with a few added features. But, everytime I drag TabControl or my tool onto the form, 2 TabPages are immediately created. I do not want these two tabpages created in designer, how can I prevent these two tabpages from being created?

Comment: 2 tabpages are created ? It is impossible unless you messed up with the control somewhere

Comment: That is what is called a *bug*.  You have code somewhere that is creating 2.  Read [ask] and take the [tour], then debug your code.

Comment: Hm, good question. The pages are created __not in your subclass but in the form__ you add it to and it happens in the form_designer.cs. Right where we ought not to mess...! You can always add a `ccTab1.TabPages.Clear();` in the form's constructor, if that is good enough..

Comment: It is the designer for TabControl that does this, that is why every TabControl you use starts out with two pages.  Deriving a class from TabControl inherits the designer.  Unfortunately the TabControlDesigner class is internal so overriding its behavior is not an option and you can't do without it.  Where to go next is not obvious.

Comment: @Pluto not true (and worthy of an up- rather than downvote, imo)

Comment: @TaW , if this question deserves upvote, then I asked a better question yesterday which got +1 upvotes but then -2 downvotes even after receiving an answer :(

Comment: @TaW , what is not true about my comment ? DId you even read it or just added a comment without any concern ?

Comment: I did what you should have done: I tested it. (Note: I misread the question myself at first as claiming extra pages were created. But it is only about the two default page any TabControl comes with.)

Comment: @TaW Okay that's different, so it's not a bug then ?

Comment: Not on OP's part. A design decision on MS's part to hide the designer template of tabcontrol and not make something like 'InitialPageCount' a property we could set.. ((Btw: times seems to fly: I don't see any question of yours from yesterday;-))

Comment: @Plutonix That is not what I was asking. The tab pages are automatically placed when I added my tool into visual studio. This was done regardless of my code. Please read my question again. You clearly haven't, the 2 tabs are added when I add any type of control that derives from a tabcontrol or the tabcontrol itself. How can this be a bug when I literally get this error when I simply include a tabcontrol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good question; unfortunately there seems to be no good answer.

The two pages are created by default for any `TabControl`, not just your subclass.

It is not in your code nor in the [MSDN sources](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/TabControl.cs).

From Hans' comment I assume that there is a 'designer template' that a form (or a top level control class, e.g. a `UserControl`) uses to add extra initialization code in the Form's `InitializeComponent` code. We should not mess with this code!

Here, in the `Form1.Designer.cs` code the tabpages are created, with their stupid names, as class-wide controls and added to the tab.

The **simplest** solution is to remove the pages in the designer **manually**.

The only other  workaround I can think of is to clear the pages e.g. in the form's constructor:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    customTab1.TabPages.Clear();
}
```

**Note**: The default `TabPages` are **not added** when you create and add the `TabControl` **in code**.

Comment: Thanks. This is very upsetting to hear that I cannot prevent these two tabs to stop being created when I place a tabcontrol down in visual studio's designer.

Comment: Yes, weird. Note that they don't get created when adding the tab in code!